# Keypressed send text to specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
var username = "test"; 
var id = "_qrt4"; 
var element = '<div class="popup-box chat-popup" id="'+ id +'">';
    element = element + '<div class="popup-head">';
    element = element + '<div class="popup-head-left">'+ username +'</div>';
    element = element + '<div class="popup-head-right"><a href="javascript:close_popup(\''+ id +'\');">&#10005;</a></div>';
    element = element + '<div style="clear: both"></div></div><div class="popup-messages"><div class="msg_body"><div class="msg_a">This is from A   </div><div class="msg_b">This is from B</div><div class="msg_push"></div></div></div><div class="msg_footer"><textarea class="msg_input" rows="4"></textarea></div></div>'

$('body').append(element) 

$('textarea').keypress(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        var msg = $(this).val();
        if(msg!=''){
            $('<div class="msg_b">'+msg+'</div>').insertBefore('.msg_push');
            $('.msg_body').scrollTop($('.msg_body')[0].scrollHeight);
        }
        $(this).val(''); 
    }
});
```

At this point, I open more than one div. One of that div in textarea I write something and the text will send for the remaining open divs.

Now, how can I after keypressed send the text to a specific div?

I tried this with div id, but no effect:

```
<div class="msg_b" id="'+ id +'">This is from B</div>
```

....

```
$('<div class="msg_b" id="'+ id +'">'+msg+'</div>').insertBefore('.msg_push');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose specific div with this selector:

```
var myDiv = $('div#id')
```

Then you can edit the div's content with the following methods:

```
myDiv.text('Your text here');
myDiv.html('<b>Your</b> html code here');
```

You can also add jQuery elements to your div:

```
myDiv.prepand($jqueryElement); // Will add $jqueryElement to the start of the div
myDiv.append($jqueryElement); // Will add $jqueryElement to the end of the div
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.msg_a').append(msg);
```